# Calculating intersection between lines with GeoTools (java)

Tags: java, intersection, algorithm, geotools

I have `ArratList<Segment>` (N segments - array size is N) when:

```
public class Segment {
    Node vertex_1;
    Node vertex_2;
}

public class Node {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
}
```

And one static point - origin point. How to work with [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) in order to get `ArrayList<boolean>` (size N) where each value is true/false regarding the question:

Is the 2 lines from origin point to both edges of the segment, intersects some other segments on their way?

For example here the result is {true, false, false} because the red line from origin point to second edge of segment 1 intersects on her way segment 3.

[image]

This question is similar to [Algorithm to find intersections in a polar plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538353/algorithm-to-find-intersections-in-a-polar-plane) on StackOverflow but the difference is that here I want to work with GeoTools instead of implementing the algorithm which involving translation of Geographic measurement units (lat/lon) into polar plane and performing some math calculation such as cross products - Not difficult but has potential for bugs, and if there is already ready open source library it's better to use it.

Because this question involving code solution, it asked also as [Calculating intersection between lines with GeoTools (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563553/calculating-intersection-between-lines-with-geotools-java) at StackOverflow.

Comment: Please do not cross post questions (though bonus point for pointing it out in the question). Also it is not clear that you have looked at GeoTools at all to see how to apply it to your problem, if you have code then edit the question and I will reopen

Comment: @iant I know GeoTools have objects like lines and points, and some functions like intersect, but I have never used this tool and struggle to find good examples how to start-the exist examples mainly concentrates on drawing maps etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JTS library, you can use `Coordinate` (your *Node*) and `LineString` (your *Segment*) objects to solve the problem:

```
// origin point
Coordinate origin = new Coordinate(5, 0);
// segments
ArrayList<LineString> segmentList = new ArrayList();
LineString segmentA = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(0, 5), new Coordinate(5, 5)});
segmentList.add(segmentA);
LineString segmentB = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(4, 3), new Coordinate(6, 3)});
segmentList.add(segmentB);
LineString segmentC = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(7, 4), new Coordinate(10, 4)});
segmentList.add(segmentC);
// result list
ArrayList<Boolean> resultList = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < segmentList.size(); i++){
    // flag to indicate intersection
    boolean intersectionResult = false;
    // get current segment
    LineString currentSegment = segmentList.get(i);
    // get segments from segment pooints to origin
    LineString startSegment = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{origin, currentSegment.getStartPoint().getCoordinate()});
    LineString endSegment = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{origin, currentSegment.getEndPoint().getCoordinate()});
    // iterate over sections
    for(int j = 0; j < segmentList.size(); j++){
        // ignore same section
        if(i != j){
            // check for intersections between segments
            if(startSegment.intersects(segmentList.get(j)) || endSegment.intersects(segmentList.get(j))){
                intersectionResult = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    // no intersection found
    resultList.add(intersectionResult);
}

// print results
for(Boolean b : resultList){
    System.out.println("intersection of segment -> " + b.booleanValue());
}
```